# How to change the src of an image from a list of images displayed using v-for?

Tags: image, vue.js, src

I am working on a MVC (V5.2.7.0), vue project (I am a vue newbie). One of the pages displays a list of product images. When an image chip is clicked it changes the corresponding big image. I am unable to access the src of the big image (getting undefined error).

1- cshtml snippet

```
    <div id="product-card-container" class="product-card__container mt-4">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column product-card" v-for="product in displayedProducts">
            <a v-bind:href="'/products/detail/' + product.Code">
            <!-- note: when a chip image is clicked, it needs to change the src of the product image -->
                <img class="product-card__image" id="product.Code + '-imgProductImage'" v-bind:src="product.ImageUrl" v-on:click="selectProduct(product.Code)" />                            
            </a>            

            <span class="product-card__name mt-2">{{product.Name}}</span>
    
            <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center mt-3">
                <section class="product-card__chip-container d-flex flex-row flex-wrap gap-2">
                    <span v-for="color in product.ColorChips">
            <!-- note: when a chip image is clicked, it needs to change the src of the product image -->
                        <img class="product-card__chip-image" id="product.Code + '-imgProductChipImage'"
                        v-bind:src="color.ImageUrl" v-bind:title="color.ColorDesc + ' ' + color.SurfaceDesc" v-on:click="changeBrandImage(product.Code,color.ImageUrl)"/>                     
                    </span>
                </section>
                <span v-if="product.AdditionalColors > 0">+{{product.AdditionalColors}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

2- js file snippet

```
changeBrandImage(productCode, imageurl) { 
        var BrandImageId = productCode + "-imgProductImage"; var BrandImage = $('#' + BrandImageId);
     if (BrandImage != null) {
            var BrandImageSrc = $(BrandImageId).attr('src');
            // BrandImageSrc is null ???
            if (BrandImageSrc != null) {
                BrandImage.attr('src', '[some image link]');
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried different jquery selector methods. None work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is that the URL of the image you're intending to set **([some image link])** is not being used.

Indeed, you're checking if BrandImageSrc (the current image URL) is non-null, then you're setting the image URL to **[some image link]** regardless of the **imageurl** passed to **changeBrandImage**.

If you intend to replace the product image with a new image when a chip is clicked, you'll need to make use of **imageurl**, which is being passed to **changeBrandImage** as a parameter. Here is how you might do it:

```
changeBrandImage(productCode, imageurl) { 
    var BrandImageId = productCode + "-imgProductImage";
    var BrandImage = $('#' + BrandImageId);

    if (BrandImage != null) {
         BrandImage.attr('src', imageurl);
    }
}
```

In this code, imageurl, which is passed as an argument, is used to change the brand image URL.